# Computing relative homology group of $S^1 \vee S^1.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Let $p$ be the wedge point of $S^1 \vee S^1.$ Compute $H_* (S^1 \vee S^1, S^1 \vee S^1 - p).$

Is there any convenient space $X$ such that $S^1 \vee S^1 - p$ deformation retracts to $X\ $? Then by long exact sequence of relative homology group and by using five lemma we can conclude that $$H_*(S^1 \vee S^1, S^1 \vee S^1 - p) \cong H_*(S^1 \vee S^1,X).$$

How do I find such $X.$ It is clear that $S^1 \vee S^1 - p$ is two disjoint copies of $1$ simplices each of which are contractible. Hence I think $S^1 \vee S^1 - p$ deformation retracts to two points. Am I right? But then how do I compute the homology group?

Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If $p$ is the wedge point then $S^1\vee S^1-p$ is the disjoint  union of two open intervals $(0,1)$. If $p$ is not the wedge point  then $S^1\vee S^1-p$ deformation retracts onto $S^1$.

Comment: @blancket I have mentioned that. But how to compute the homology then? Both copies of $(0,1)$ are contractible. Right? So $S^1 \vee S^1 - p$ deformation retracts to two points as I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Use Homology Long Exact Sequence of Pair.

Comment: @Sumanta by using long exact sequence of pair I find that $H_n (S^1 \vee S^1, \{p,q\}) = 0,$ for $n \geq 2.$

Comment: @Sumanta I think $H_0 (S^1 \vee S^1, \{p,q\}) = 0.$ The reason behind this is the following $:$ Here $(S^1 \vee S^1, \{p,q\})$ is a CW pair and hence it has HEP. Therefore $$H_0(S^1 \vee S^1, \{p,q\}) \cong \widetilde {H_0} (S^1 \vee S^1/ \{p,q\}) = 0$$ since $S^1 \vee S^1/\{p,q\}$ is path connected. So we need only to find the first relative homology group.

Comment: For $0$-th homology: If $X$ be a path-connected  space and $A$ be a non-empty subspace of $X$, then $H_0(X,A)=0$.

Comment: For $1$-st homology, use Excision Theorem: Let $K$ be a subset of a space $X$ and let $U$ be a neighborhood of the closure of $K$. Then the
inclusion $(U, U  \backslash K) → (X, X\backslash  K)$ induces for each $n \geq 0$ an isomorphism $H_n(U, U\backslash  K)\xrightarrow{\simeq}H_n (X, X\backslash K)$. Here in our case, take $K=p$, and $U$ to be a small contractible open neighborhood of $K$. Now, to calculate $H_1(U, U\backslash K)$ again, use homology long exact sequence. Note that $H_1(U)=0, H_0(U\backslash K)\cong \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Sumanta In the excision theorem you are using what is the pair? Is it $(X,X \setminus K)\ $? I think it is the case. Here $X \setminus U \subseteq X \setminus K \subseteq X$ with $\overline {X \setminus U} = X \setminus U \subseteq \text {int}\ (X \setminus K) = X \setminus K,$ if $X$ is Hausdorff. Also $(X \setminus K) \setminus (X \setminus U) = U \setminus K.$ So by excision theorem we have the required isomorphism induced by the inclusion. Am I right? One another question how do you get $H_0(U \setminus K) = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z\ $?

Comment: @Sumanta if we take a small neighborhood $U$ around the wedge point $p$ and then remove $p$ from that don't we get four lines? After drawing picture I get such things because any such neighborhood will intersect upper and lower circular arcs of the both the circles in the wedge at some point. Am I missing something?

Comment: If it can be figured out what is the map $H_0 (U \setminus K) \xrightarrow {\varphi} H_0(U)$ then $H_1(U,U \setminus K) \cong \text {Ker}\ \varphi.$ Now how do I figure out the map $\varphi\ $?

Comment: Sure, you are right. My bad! $\widetilde H_1(U\backslash K)=0\to \widetilde H_1(U)=0\to H_1(U,U\backslash K)\to \widetilde H_0(U\backslash K)=\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z\to \widetilde H_0(U)=0$

Comment: If $\{X_\lambda\}$ is the set of all path components of $X$ then $H_n(X)\cong \sum_\lambda H_n(X_\lambda)$ for all $n\geq 0$. Now, $U\backslash K=U\backslash p$ homeomorphic to $(0,1)\sqcup (0,1)\sqcup(0,1)\sqcup(0,1)$.

Comment: @Sumanta do we have $$H_* (U, U \setminus K) = \begin{cases} \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z\ & \text {if}\ * = 1 \\ 0\ & \text {elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

Comment: @Sumanta I got it just after I asked you. I know the fact that you have mentioned in your comment. Sorry for that. Many many thanks for your invaluable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove this question from the unsolved/unanswered queue, I am writing all my comments in this answer.

Let $X:=\Bbb S^1\lor \Bbb S^1$ and $A:=X\backslash p$ where $p$ is the wedge point. Consider the reduced homology long exact sequence of the pair $(X,A)$: $$\cdots\to \widetilde H_n(A)\to \widetilde H_n(X)\to H_n(X,A)\to \widetilde H_{n-1}(A)\to \cdots$$ Note that $A\cong (0,1)\sqcup (0,1)$, so $$\widetilde H_n(A)=\begin{cases}\Bbb Z&\text{ if }n=0,\\0&\text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}\text{ and } \widetilde H_n(X)=\begin{cases}\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z&\text{ if }n=1,\\ 0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ Hence, $\color{red}{H_n(X,A)=0\text{ for }n\geq 2}$.

Now, $X$ is path-connected and $A$ is a non-empty subspace of $X$, so by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3293201/591889) we have $\color{red} {H_0(X,A)=0}$.

Finally, we have to compute $H_1(X, A)$. Let $U$ be a small open contractible neighborhood of $p$ such that $U\backslash p\cong (0,1)\sqcup(0,1)\sqcup(0,1)\sqcup(0,1)$. Now, excising  the closed set $X\backslash U$ from the pair $(X,X\backslash p)$ we have the inclusion induced isomorphism $H_n(U,U\backslash p)\to H_n(X,X\backslash p)$ for each $n\geq 0$.

In particular, $H_1(U,U\backslash p)\simeq H_1(X,X\backslash p)$. Now, consider a part of the reduced homology long exact sequence of the pair $(U,U\backslash p)$: $$\cdots\to \widetilde H_1(U\backslash p)\to \widetilde H_1(U)\to H_1(U,U\backslash p)\to \widetilde H_0(U\backslash p)\to \widetilde H_0(U)\to H_0(U,U\backslash p)\to 0$$Now, $U$ is path connected implies $\widetilde H_0(U)=0$ and $U\backslash p$ has four path components implies $\widetilde H_0(U\backslash p)\simeq \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$. Also, $U$ is contarctioble implies $\widetilde H_1(U)=0$. Therefore, $$\color{red}{H_1(X,A)=H_1(X,X\backslash p)\simeq H_1(U,U\backslash p)\simeq \widetilde H_0(U\backslash p)\simeq \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z.}$$